# Finding ID's from 1 table and finding the same IDs from another table with time conditions SQL

Tags: sql, relational-database

I've got two tables. Customer info and transaction table (transaction level not customer level).

Customer table:

- id
- Created season (i.e 2012-2013)

Transaction table:
 - id
 - Transaction date (i.e 2012-01-02 15:33:06)

First question:

I want to find out how many distinct customers in the current season (2017-18) have not transacted since Jan 2019

Second question:

I want to find out how many distinct customers in the current season (2017-18) have not transacted from Jan 2018.

Third question:

I want to find out how many distinct customers in the current season (2017-18) have never transacted something.

My code

```
SELECT count(distinct a.id), a.season
From(
Select a.id, a.season
From customer as a 
Join transaction as b
On a.id = b.id
Where a.created season = '2017-18' and MAX(b.transaction_date) < '2019-02-01')
Group by 2
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't code, stack overflow will do this for you... Please give us your code. And there is no relation between your tables, you need a foreign key.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by there is no relation between the two tables when the id is the primary key where I link the two tables

Comment: share sample data and output

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `not exists` subquery:

```
select count(*)
from customers c 
where c.season = '2017-2018' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from transactions t
                  where t.id = c.id and t.transaction_date >= '2019-01-01'
                 );
```

All three of your queries follow the same format.